# Image not post on instagram from ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, instagram

I am integrating Instagram into my application using the `instagram-ios-sdk`. I can successfully `login` to Instagram and obtain an access token, but after that when I am try to post a picture using `UIDocumentInteractionController` from `UIImagePickerController`, the image is not posting. The code to send a picture is given below:

```
(void)_startUpload:(UIImage *) image {
    NSLog(@"Image Object = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"file url  %@",jpgPath);

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] init];
igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];
NSLog(@"File Url = %@",igImageHookFile);

    documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];

    [documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

(UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL  usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
    NSLog(@"%@",fileURL);
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
        [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}
```

I converted the image to `.ig` format, with a resolution of (612 *612). But still the image is not posting on `Instagram`. Am I missing something? Can any one help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: same problem here. :( if you did figure out please can you share me what you have done.

Comment: Did any of you guys figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your code, you're not assigning the return value of `setupControllerWithURL: usingDelegate:` to an object, so that method isn't actually accomplishing anything, just creating a new instance of UIDocumentInteractionController and discarding it.

Secondly, from the documentation:

```
"Note that the caller of this method needs to retain the returned object."
```

You're not retaining the document controller (or assigning it to a strongly referenced property in the case of ARC) from what I can tell.

Try this - 
In your @interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;
```

In your @implementation:

```
self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.documentController.delegate = self;
self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
[self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Also, the line `NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] init];` is unnecessary because in the next line `igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];` you're creating a new instance and discarding the first one. Just use `NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];`

Comment: i done this all but the result is same the image is not posting in this, Is it possible it only work in device not in simulator.what can i do???

Comment: i tried  [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
 and it worked thanks daltonclaybrook..:)

Comment: Can i know that image is shared successfully to instagram? I want to update my DB only when the image is shared successfully.